# Jquery multiselect - Togggle hide optgroup issues

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, jquery-ui-multiselect

I have implemented the [jquery multiselect addon](http://www.erichynds.com/blog/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget) and got it working fine. I have a long list of select options and are divided by optgroups. While optgroups organizes my long list but still users still have to scroll for a while to get to the bottom option. I am simply looking for a solution to have the optgroup collapsed by default and un-collapsed when you click on the group.

At the moment when you click on the optgroup it automatically selects all options under it which I would like to prevent and instead replace that with a hide function instead. I know that jquery by default cannot target a select's optgroup but the Jquery Multiple select addon has an event handler that apparently allows you too. If you scroll a bit half way down [their site](http://www.erichynds.com/blog/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget) it gives you all the event handlers this addon supports. I was really interested in the `optgrouptoggle` event:

> Fires when an optgroup label is clicked on.  This event receives the original event object as the first argument,  and a hash of values as the second argument: js
>   `$("#multiselect").bind("multiselectoptgrouptoggle",  function(event, ui){ 
>       /*
>       event: the original event object, most likely "click" 
>       ui.inputs: an array of the checkboxes  (DOM elements) inside the optgroup 
>       ui.label: the text of the  optgroup 
>       ui.checked: whether or not the checkboxes were  checked or unchecked in the toggle (boolean) 
>       */ 
>   });`

I tried implementing a show hide function as follows but I still new with jquery and might be botching this completely. Any help would be appreciated.

http://jsfiddle.net/akhyp/1986/

```
$("#selected_items").bind("multiselectoptgrouptoggle", function(event, ui){ 
    $(this).children().show();
}, function() {
    $(this).children().hide();
 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few problems with this approach, some in your code, some in the plugin's API:

1. Your demo code references `$("#selected_items")`, which is nowhere in your markup. Change the selector to `$("select")` to match your declaration of the `multiselect` above. Better still, cache the jQuery object in a variable: `var $multiselect = $('select');`
2. The docs specify using `bind` to attach an event listener, but `bind` is deprecated in recent versions of jQuery. Use `on` instead.
3. You're passing two functions to the `on/bind` method--it only takes one. Instead of using `hide()` and `show()`, you can just use [jQuery's `toggle` method](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/).
4. The `multiselect` plugin isn't structuring its generated markup semantically, so `optgroups` and their child `option` elements are translated into straight-up `li` elements, with the `optgroup` and `option` elements as siblings. That means you can't use `children()` the way you would hope. However, the API provides you with a way to find the checkboxes that were associated with the `optgroup`: `ui.inputs`. From those, you can find each of the parent `li` elements and hide them. Unfortunately, it doesn't look like the API gives you a way to directly address them, but you can use a code snippet like so:

   `var parentLiOfInput = function(input) {
       return $(input).closest('li');
   };
   var $listEls = ui.inputs.map(parentLiOfInput);
   // $listEls is now an array of jQuery objects
   // Note this isn't the same as a jQuery wrapped set--
   // you can't do $listEls.hide(), for example.`
5. Hiding the generated "option" elements will prevent the plugin from working--it uses a jQuery selector to toggle the checkboxes, and that selector relies on the associated elements to be visible.

That last point is the blocker: Once you hide the checkbox, the plugin will fail on the next optgroup click. **[Demo of the failing behavior.](http://jsfiddle.net/Palpatim/h49mw2ye/)**

I don't really see any options for you at this point, without directly modifying the code of the plugin.

Comment: Really appreciate the detailed reponse on this this. I will continue digging for some sort of work around on this, if this get stoo complicated I might look for a different Jquery mulitselect addon and work from there.

Comment: Thanks. If you find the response useful, feel free to vote it up without accepting it to indicate to future users of the site that the answer was of some help with your issue. Good luck with your search.

Comment: After really digging into the the documentation of this addon I found that I could use the following code: `$(function () {
$("#selected_items").multiselect({ optGroupCollapsible: true });
});` but this also required me to use an updated version of the addon. I cant find the link I found these details but if I find ill make sure to share that along.

Comment: Here you go https://github.com/ehynds/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget. If you download the whole package there is some demos pages in there you can try and there's one called optgroup you can see the HTML page here https://github.com/aerichmond/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/blob/master/demos/optgroups.htm. The only thing I need to figure out is how to make it collapsed status upon load of the page instead of having everything expanded upon load.